# How to modify huge patch file properly?

Tags: linux, kernel, patch

I have this [patch](http://mirrors.muarf.org/grsecurity/test/grsecurity-3.0-3.15.2-201406262058.patch.gz).

I want to disable patching of `Makefile` and `drivers/video/logo/logo_linux`.

What is best way of doing this?
Do I edit it, and delete that specific entries? If so, is there a tool that will do it properly while keeping correct structure of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is version control.

Is the software you are patching under version control? If not you could put it under version control, apply the patch, then selectively un-apply the changes you don't want. This can be done in Mercurial, for example, with

```
hg revert filename
```

which will remove the local changes, e.g. "patching of Makefile and drivers/video/logo/logo_linux".

To get a revised patch is as simple as

```
hg diff
```

if you are using Mercurial, or (probably)

```
git diff
```

An alternative is to put only the files that are going to be patched under version control. A handy utility for discovering what files will be patched by a patch file is diffstat.

```
diffstat patchfile
```