# How to take the log of the patches we applied?

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, patch

So here's my question I recently downloaded the linux kernel patch 3.4.101 and i applied this patch directly to the base 3.4.0 with this command:

```
$ cd /kernel source directory
$ gzip -cd ../path to patch/patch-3.4.101 | patch -p1
```

And I got some failed hunks… but since the patch was too large I was not able to analyze all the hunks and rejections… so here goes my main question:

How can I get the complete log of this patching process?

Comment: You look in the rejections and analyse them

Comment: You bring the source code under revision control (or branch if it already is) and commit the patches with the patchcommand as comment after application.

Comment: Are you completely sure you started from a clean 3.4.0 directory? I ask because the patch is specifically designed to apply cleanly to that, and I verified that I indeed get no rejections at all.

Comment: See my answer to a rather similar question here - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139817/4671. In fact this question is similar enough that it might be a possible dupe.

Comment: @hvd Ya actually this is for my mobile's kernel...i did patch 3.4.1 to 3.4.10 to it... there were no rejections...so i took the fresh source and patched 3.4.101...and there were some 30-40 rejections roughly...my question is tat i can see only the final 6-7 rejections...and the rejections during the beginning doesnt get holded to the terminal....so i want a complete log of the patching in the terminal in a txt file to analyse every rejections...

Comment: Now I'm getting confused. Are you attempting to apply the 3.4.101 patch to 3.4.0, or to 3.4.10? Only the former will work, and that's what your question says you're attempting, but your comment suggests the latter.

Comment: @hvd No i clearly mentioned "took fresh source"...i didnt apply the patch on 3.4.10... i applied it on the fresh untouched source i.e 3.4.0...

Comment: @DhineshRavi Okay, that's good. Nonetheless, something is very wrong: like I said, I downloaded 3.4 myself, along with the 101 patch, and verified that the patch applies cleanly, before commenting. I happened to download the `.xz`-compressed versions, but that shouldn't make any difference. The actual patch command is the exact `patch -p1` that you also used.

Comment: @hvd actually b4 attempting i made a --dry-run the were many hunk failures...and for the .rej files i applied the patch...

Comment: @hvd I found  the reasons for rejection...these hunks were already patched by my mobile company...so these were rejected ..the sources got compiled alright...thanks for helping me with this...

Answer (score 1):

When `patch` fails, it saves the bit that fails in a `.rej` file.

Since you have already run it, you will have those files already. You can find them with `find . -name \*.rej`.

To get an actual log, you'd have to pipe the output and errors from `patch` through a pager, such as `less`: `gzip -dc patch.gz | patch -p1 2>&1 | less`. `patch` does not maintain any log of the parts of the patch that were applied successfully, so there is no way to get a complete log after `patch` has already been run. Of course, to make this work, you'd need to first clean up your directory: it won't provide useful results if run a second time.

Note that as mentioned in the comments, in this particular case, the fact that you get *any* rejection is a very big problem and you should not attempt to resolve conflicts by hand: make sure you get the exact matching versions of the base tarball and patch. The exact versions you list show no errors whatsoever when I run

```
rm -rf linux-3.4
tar xzvf ~/Downloads/linux-3.4.tar.gz
cd linux-3.4
gzip -dc ~/Downloads/patch-3.4.101.gz | patch -p1 2>&1 | less -S
```

but this does give me the patch output you're hoping to get too.

Comment: Although what you write makes sense, your answer addresses issues with failed patches, and doesn't answer how to log the process of applying patches at all. And that is the OPs question

Comment: @Anthon Fair point. The OP is asking for the log of the process in order to examine the log to find the rejections. My answer gives the rejections directly without going through the log, so I think it makes a useful answer even if it doesn't address the question exactly as written.

Comment: @Anthon Nonetheless, edited to more directly answer the question too.

Comment: Anyways thanks to both of u...i just made a ctrl+f and searched for .rej... i got nearly 61 rejections..so i better will revert back to older sub-versions...